# Color all values in an array

Tags: arrays, vba

```
        Sub arraytestingwow()
            Dim countertest As Integer
            Dim countermax As Integer
            Dim arraysuper(1 To 6, 0 To 4) As Variant

            countermax = 6

            For countertest = 1 To countermax

                    arraysuper(countertest, 0) = Range("a1").Offset(countertest, 0)
                    arraysuper(countertest, 1) = Range("b1").Offset(countertest, 0)
                    arraysuper(countertest, 2) = Range("c1").Offset(countertest, 0)
                    arraysuper(countertest, 3) = Range("d1").Offset(countertest, 0)
                    arraysuper(countertest, 4) = Range("e1").Offset(countertest, 0)

            Next

            Range("G1:K" & countermax - 1).Value = arraysuper

            'arraysuper.interior.colorindex = 3?????? Set all values not blank with color
        End Sub
```

There are headers in my row so I coded for it.
How do I make it so that all values in my array that are not blank have a color?
There will be over 100,000 rows so I am looking for the best way to do it (otherwise I'd use a loop with if statements)

Comment: What's wrong with a loop, exactly?

Comment: conditional formatting?

Comment: Can't use conditional formatting because there are multiple colors. Each color is a different source

Comment: @Blorgbeard Performance issues since there are over 150,000 rows and 40 columns. I was just wondering if there was a fast way to do it with arrays.

Comment: there is no way to do it with array, as the array contains only values, and .interior.colorindex doesn't accept array. How is the color determined .. bu the cell value?

Comment: Color determined will be the array. There will be an array for each source which loads into one big spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You could colour all cells and then wipe the blanks.  Here is a demo of how to get the blanks for a block of cells.  First run the top procedure to write some data onto a sheet, with some holes.

```
Sub SetUpSwissCheeseData_RunOnceToBegin()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(3, 3))

    Dim vData As Variant
    vData = Application.Evaluate("{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}")

    rng.Value2 = vData
    rng.Cells(1, 2).Value = Null
    rng.Cells(2, 1).Value = Null
    rng.Cells(3, 3).Value = Null

End Sub

Sub GetBlanks()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(3, 3))

    Dim rngBlanks As Excel.Range
    Set rngBlanks = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    Debug.Assert rngBlanks.Address = "$B$1,$A$2,$C$3"
    Stop


End Sub
```